# What is the cheapest substance that does not allow any EM wave to pass through them?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, material-science

Substances that can protect from any EM wave of any frequency i.e. even gamma rays, provided the cheapest substance.

Comment: This is a question about how much different conductors cost, which is not a physics question proper.

Comment: D/v for the above reason

Comment: Any substance will, provided it is thick enough.

Comment: "Cheapest" - I read somewhere a suggestion to get used single-use radiation padding from a medical facility. If they do not recycle, it might be free.

Comment: Obviously, a tinfoil hat ;)

Answer (score 4):

There's not any 1 substance which meets your criteria, and "cheapest" is very subjective due to the idea of cost/benefit.  One layering which is used extensively to reduce background radiation for nuclear physics measurements is lead/cadmium/copper, from outside to inside.

Lead knocks down the gamma background but still has a ~90 keV x-ray and some Compton photons. The cadmium will absorb low energy gammas and produce some ~40 keV x-rays. It is also a conductor, so one could make a radio-frequency shield from it. The copper absorbs the cadmium x-rays and has some very low energy x-rays. Copper also can form a radio-frequency shield. But you can't totally eliminate everything. There will always be some radiation if the temperature is above 0K.